# Transferring XWPFDocument to InputBinary

Tags: java, apache-poi, inputstream

Is there a way to convert an `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument` object to any sub-class of `java.io.InputStream` (maybe `java.io.FileInputStream`) without having to consider the `java.io.File`object where the said document is referred from the hierarchy below.

```
java.io.File                               => The path of the .docx file
java.io.FileInputStream                    => The InputStream to be used for JDBC
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument => Retrieve elements in the document
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to convert a `XPWFDocument` object to an `InputStream` object.

Comment: But why? Why do you think that would be a good idea? What is it that you were trying to do in the first place when you came up with this plan?

Comment: I was trying to remove the `java.io` package in my entity and replacing it with the `XWPFDocument` since I am only referring to a `.docx` file with is initialized upload file load.